# YDN-DB - Incorrect results using mixed data types with SortedMerge

Tags: indexeddb, ydn-db

I'm using the excellent YDN-DB as part of a complicated 'dashboard' web page that allows a user to download a large amount of information and then search & filter the data how they wish.

The data comes down in the form of 1 UNID and 6 columns of visible data which I am storing using a YDN schema like this:

```
var schema = {
    stores: [
        {
            name: 'test', keyPath: 'unid', autoIncrement: false,
            indexes: [
                {keyPath: 'a', type: 'TEXT'},
                {keyPath: 'b', type: 'TEXT'},
                {keyPath: 'c', type: 'TEXT'},
                {keyPath: 'd', type: 'DATE'},
                {keyPath: 'e', type: 'TEXT'},
                {keyPath: 'f', type: 'TEXT'}
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

The user then can then place a filter on any of the six columns above. The code to build the filters looks like this, and uses the YDN KeyRange to filter the data by the values requested by the user.

```
var filterArr = []
var resultArr = [];

filterArr.push(new ydn.db.IndexIterator('test', 'a', ydn.db.KeyRange.only('search value 1')));
filterArr.push(new ydn.db.IndexIterator('test', 'b', ydn.db.KeyRange.only('search value 2')));
.. [Continue adding filters for more columns if necessary etc] ..

var req = db.scan(new ydn.db.algo.SortedMerge(resultArr), filterArr);

req.then(function() {
    db.values('test', resultArr).done(function(results) {
        .. [Display code goes here] ..
    })
})
```

So for matched values, this works fine. My problem however, is that the user can specify a date range for column D, so I have changed one of the filterArr lines above like this:

```
filterArr.push(new ydn.db.IndexIterator('test', 'd', ydn.db.KeyRange.bound(1389571200000, 1390435200000, false, false)));
```

This leads to incorrect results from the search. It appears to happen only when multiple filterArr values are specified. If I filter column D on its own, it seems to work.

Sorry for the complicated query and really hoping for some kind of answer. I have spent some time debugging the SortedMerge JS and my limited knowledge suggests that something is going wrong with the result of each call to the ydn.db.cmp function, so I wondered whether this was a bug in YDN DB?

Comment: Have you tested in both indexeddb and websql? Same problem?

Comment: I have tried in IE11 & Chrome, how can I force WebSQL?

Comment: Use `mechanisms` in the option.

Comment: Alternatively you can try with giving the data type of DATE. That will enforce encoding.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see from you code, column 'd' should be INTEGER, or query should use date like:

```
ydn.db.KeyRange.bound(toDate(1389571200000),toDate(1390435200000), false, false)
```

EDIT:

Sorry, key joining algorithm only work for equi-join. Range will not work. You can use one range query however, but require six compound index [a, d], [b, d], [c, d], d, [e, d], [f, d] and join using ZigZeg merge. Detail here http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/nosql-query.html You can also find requirement for equi join.

Current ZigZeg is faster then SortedMerge since IndexedDB API spec 1 does not have require methods. However v2 is coming with require methods, namely `openKeyCursor` and `continuePrimaryKey`. Result of ZigZeg is sorted by d, whereas SortedMerge is sorted by primary key.

Comment: Thank you - I put the numbers there for clarity. My code actually does a `new Date()`. I switched the schema for column D to INTEGER, and the IndexIterator to `Number( [date_value] )` but it still doesn't show all of the expected results.

Comment: Don't provide any type information. Anyways if you provide me a unit test I will fix.

Comment: Thank you, I will set up a fiddle for it and post here. Excellent software by the way, beautifully written and very useful :)

Comment: Sorry, you cannot use range, it will not work. It is explain here http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/nosql-query.html.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing a `Date` object, store the timestamp representation instead:

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
```

Since a timestamp is an integer, you can then effectively use a key range on it.