# IndexedDB using YDN-DB: How to query object store on multiple filters

Tags: indexeddb, ydn-db

Working on an offline html5 project, I have the following store:

```
            outreach_answers = {
                name: 'outreach_answers',
                keyPath: ['device_unique_id', 'outreach_id', 'question_id'],
                indexes: [
                    {
                        keyPath: 'outreach_id'
                    },
                    {
                        keyPath: 'section_id'
                    },
                    {
                        keyPath: 'question_id'
                    },
                    {
                        keyPath: 'answer'
                    }
                ]
            }
```

I need to make a query such as this:

```
SELECT records FROM outreach_answers 
WHERE question_id = 12 AND section_id = 2 AND outreach_id = 'AB-56'
```

Most of the methods I have been able to use (e.g. `db.get()`, `db.values()` or even `db.from()...where().list()`) seem quite restrictive.

Of these, the last method seemed to be the most promising, until I really required to run a query that should filter on `question_id`, `section_id` and `outreach_id` at the same time.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can find [article about multiple filtered query with YDN-DB](http://dev.yathit.com/ydn-db/nosql-query.html) and some tips on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22347953/ydn-db-incorrect-results-using-mixed-data-types-with-sortedmerge).

Comment: Thanks @Kyaw. Via the first link, the closest thing I found was the section: `Coupound Index` and the example that starts with `key_range = ydn.db.KeyRange.bound(['SA', 'A'], ['SA', 'B']);`. My observations: 1. My three fields of interest are not on one compound index, must they be? 2. I haven't been able to wrap my head around those `Iterator` methods, are they the only way to achieve my goal? 3. To use the Iterator, it looks like I need to have an extra ydn.db module outside of `Query`, right?

Comment: @IfediOkonkwo unfortunately both of your observation are correct. These two approaches have yet to implement in Query module, so that it is easier to user. There are some attempt, you can try calling `where` multiple times.

Comment: Really? Didn't realize I could chain multiple `where` methods on one `db.from`. If it is so, then there's at least a work-around. I'm going to take a look at that. Thank you.